# Boost (header only) integration with Cocos2d-X Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, boost, path, cocos2d-x

I am working on a cross-platform cocos2dx game and have a problem configuring the Boost framework with Eclipse. As of now, the project is not well organised, since the Android workspace lie completely outside the remaining project structure.

```
Android project: /Users/usr/Documents/cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4/proj/proj.android
iOS project:     /Users/usr/projects/proj/ios
Classes:         /Users/usr/projects/proj/classes
Boost:           /Users/usr/projects/proj/libs/boost
```

I will be mostly using `Boost::Geometry` which is a header-only library. In Xcode, it's working fine.

But when I add the Boost path `/Users/usr/projects/proj/libs/boost` to *Project Properties* → *C/C++ general* → *Paths and Symbols* → *GNU C and GNU C++* and include any header (`#include <boost/foreach.hpp>`) in my source, Eclipse couldn't find the file and shows:

```
fatal error: boost/foreach.hpp: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the header search path in your Android.mk file in the Android project's `jni` directory. In the current standard template you have something like

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes
```

in there. To add your Boost directory, change it to

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../projects/proj/libs
```

if the `libs` directory is where the Boost headers are.